# Making a thread wait two seconds before continuing in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wait

I'm having trouble making a thread wait for two seconds without blocking the GUI. The most simple wait method I know is `Thread.Sleep(2000);`. If you can use some examples of timers or others that I'm not aware of, please do because I'm not too familiar with the ways of coding.

```
private void run_program_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.Text == "Drive forwards and back")
    {
        stop.IsEnabled = true;

        EngineA(90); //Makes EngineA drive at 90% power
        EngineB(90); //Makes EngineB drive at 90% power

        // Basicly it has to wait two seconds here

        EngineA(-90); // -90% power aka. reverse
        EngineB(-90); // -90% power

        // Also two seconds here

        EngineA(0); // Stops the engine
        EngineB(0); // Stops
        EngineC();
     }
}
```

Comment: Please look at the edited source of your post for an example of how to post a block of code - there was no need for all those backticks.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using C# 5, the simplest approach is to make the method `async`:

```
private async void RunProgramClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Reverse the logic to reduce nesting and use "early out"
    if (comboBox1.Text != "Drive forwards and back")
    {
        return;
    }

    stop.IsEnabled = true;
    EngineA(90);
    EngineB(90);

    await Task.Delay(2000);

    EngineA(-90);
    EngineB(-90);

    await Task.Delay(2000);

    EngineA(0);
    EngineB(0);
    EngineC();
}
```

Comment: I'm using C# 4.0, And I get two errors when using async.  Error one: The type or namespace name 'async' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assmbly refrence?) And the second error: Invalid token 'void' in class, struct, or interface member declaration.

Comment: @DeliciousCake: Well yes, you would - because async was introduced in C# 5. Hence the "If you're using C# 5" part of my answer. Any chance you could upgrade to VS2012 or VS2013? It would make your life much simpler...

Comment: @Jon_Skeet Unfortunetly not :/ Tech school dosn't allow us to install programs, I need to figure this out within' 1½ week or I'll might fail my exam :(

Comment: @DeliciousCake: In that case I suggest you use a `DispatcherTimer`. That will let you effectively defer some work for later.

Comment: @Jon_Skeet Got an example of how to make wait the two seconds within two commands? It'll help alot if I can move on from this problem

Comment: @DeliciousCake: Well have you looked at `DispatcherTimer` and tried to use it? It's not going to be *terribly* simple code (not as simple as "just wait here"), but you should try doing it yourself first - and then probably ask a new question with your attempted code if you run into problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// WPF Wait
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="seconds"></param>
    public static void Wait(double seconds)
    {
        var frame = new DispatcherFrame();
        new Thread((ThreadStart)(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
            frame.Continue = false;
        })).Start();
        Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
    }
```

Comment: There are at least a dozen duplicates of this question on SO, and this is THE solution

Answer (score 0):

I found this approach simpler,

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0,0,2)));
Task.WaitAll(new[] { task });
```

*Late answer, but i hope it should be useful for someone.*