# How to stop the c# wpf application at a line for some seconds and then move to next line

Tags: c#, wpf

```
 var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/9.png");
 var bitmap = new BitmapImage(uri);
 p1.Source = bitmap;
 Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

In my scenario, my program should set the source of the image named p1 first to 9.png and then it should wait for 2 seconds but it first waits for 2 seconds first and then sets the source of the image named p1.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: actually its a flip flop game, i want to show some image for two seconds here as a background and then immediately change its background to original.

Comment: Thread.Sleep blocks your main UI thread before it even has a chance to show the image.  Instead you could use a System.Theading.Timer to change the image after 2 seconds.

Comment: I don't think this has to do with waiting at that line it's just that when you change the source it does not update until you are finished with that function. You have to create some type of timer for your desired effect.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21547744/2224701

Comment: Just a guess: try `await Task.Delay(2000);` instead of `Thread.Sleep(2000);`. In the next line you can change the bitmap again. Using `await` should let the UI run and update the background.

Comment: @vyrp: It needs to be called from inside an async method.

Comment: @Jakob Christensen Yes, it does. I don't know the context of the posted code. If it just just a click handler, just marking the method as async is enough. If it is more complex, then another solution is needed.

Comment: Thankyou vyrp and Jakob it worked by async method.